# How to track, measure, manipulate and/or synchronize the phases of trapped ion qubits

Tags: laser, optoelectronics

I am working on a simulation of the Honeywell trapped ion quantum computer. The papers say that it tracks the phases of the qubits using "opto-electronics" but it doesn't give any detail.

Comment: Pretty sure it does involve lasers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Honeywell paper, [HQS-QCCD Demonstration](https://www.honeywell.com/content/dam/honeywell/files/HQS-QCCD-Demonstration.pdf) by J. M. Pino et.al. seems to hint that,

> We store quantum information in the \$^{171}Yb^{+2}S_{1/2}\$ hyperfine “clock” states, \$∣0⟩ ≡ ∣F = 0, m_F = 0⟩ and ∣1⟩ ≡ ∣F =
> 1, m_F = 0⟩\$, with a frequency splitting of 12.642821GHz\$^{[15]}\$, where \$F\$ and \$m_F\$ are the quantum numbers for total
> angular momentum and its z-projection.

Then,

> We impose a quantization axis parallel to the trap surface at a 45°
> angle with respect to the RF-null. This 5G field is uniform between the two zones to within 0.2mG, creating non-uniformity in the measured qubit frequencies of less than 1Hz. All laser systems are frequency and intensity stabilized via closed-loop feedback, and all beam alignment is handled through automated routines.

So (multiple) lasers are definitely being used.  Now as for *what optical frequency* and other parameters necessary, well, likely only the authors of that paper can say. But it seems like these lasers are on the edge of modern capability.

Comment: It is clear that they use lasers; is it clear that the lasers are used for qubit phase tracking?

Comment: That sounds plausible, but sorry I do not know with certainty.  Also perhaps another aspect could be "read", such as spin, entanglement, superposition, etc.  Ironically, *coherence* would be a perfect target for the [pure] laser light, but reporting when a qubit has died seems pretty useless if that doesn't "read" it in the process.

Comment: I think it would be useful to know when a qubit has died. BTW, the energy split between the two qubit levels corresponds to 12 GHz, which seems to be microwave rather than optical. I wonder how the lasers couple to the qubits.

Comment: The paper says "all quantum gate operations are (done by) using lasers..."